# Dungeon Maze Game - Directional Issues

Tags: c#, text, console

This may or may not be a duplicate, I've found many many maze games and dungeon games on the website but I cannot find exactly what I am looking for.

I'm trying to make a game that has a maze in which User presses an arrow key to navigate. Each dungeon you enter you either face a threat, or receive a treasure chest (These parts are sorted).

The issue I'm having is that if the player is going back to a previously explored room, I want it to be empty rather than restarting. I'm struggling with the navigation as I have currently hard coded the navigation (for first 3 rooms).

```
bool check = room.CheckCompletetion(room);
            if(check == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[Directions: North]\n");
                Console.WriteLine("The entrance room is complete, choose where you want to go.");
                ConsoleKeyInfo DirectionE = Console.ReadKey();

            }
            else
            {
                room.GenerateInteraction(room, hero);
                room.Completed = 1;
            }
```

Like the code above, I have 3 rooms exactly the same but all with the different directions. Then I noticed that I'd have the issue that even with my room.Completed. If the user goes back two rooms, my nested IF statements would be absolutely massive which is not exactly what I want...

My room class is currently as follows

```
class Room
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public int Completed = 0;
    public Random r = new Random();
    public static Random r1 = new Random();


    public Room(int id, string name)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

public void Passage(Room room, Hero hero, ConsoleKeyInfo direction)
    {

        bool checkroom = room.CheckCompletetion(room);

        if (checkroom == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("empty");
        }
        if (checkroom == false)
        {
            room.GenerateInteraction(room, hero);
        }
    }


    public bool CheckCompletetion(Room room)
    {
        if (room.Completed == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

(Needs some fixing also but trying to sort the navigation first)
If you need anything else just ask - Thanks

Comment: Keepig roomstates in memory shouldnt be that expensive, or, you have to write them to disk ..

Comment: Is this the case even if you're only keeping it through run time? @BugFinder

Comment: yes, nothing wrong with keeping things on disk if the area is really likely to be a memory issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your room class you could capture values as North, East, South and West, which could correspond to the room that is connected in that direction, see below:

```
 class Room
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public int Completed = 0;
    public Random r = new Random();
    public static Random r1 = new Random();


    public int North;
    public int East;
    public int South;
    public int West;



    public Room(int id, string name, int north, int east, int south, int west)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.North = north;
        this.East = east;
        this.South = south;
        this.West = west;
    }
```

When you create a new instance of room, either manually, or randomly provide the room number that is connected for each direction.

e.g. Below is a new instance of a room where id = 1, name = "Room1", north = 2, east = 0, south = 0 and west = 0.

```
 Room room1 = new Room(1, "Room1", 2, 0, 0, 0);
```

Room 2, which would be north of room 1 could look something like

```
  Room room2 = new Room(2, "Room2", 0, 0, 1, 3);
```

Which would mean room two was joined by room1 at the south and room3 at the west.

In your code you could capture the current room and the direction choice which would identify the next room etc, for example:

```
Room currentRoom;
choice = Console.ReadLine();
if (choice.ToLower() == "n" || choice == "north")
{
nextroom = room.north;
}
 switch (nextRoom)
{


 case 1:
 currentRoom = room1;
 room = currentRoom;
 break;
 }
```

When you first create a room, you would have your roomCompleted bool as false, once the room had been played this would then be changed to true. You can add an if statement that will see that the room has already been completed and will present the user with an "empty room".